Extension of the solution of a Cauchy problem
I am trying to study the solution of the following Cauchy problem:
\begin{align*}
y'&=\frac{x^2y^2}{1-y}e^{-xy}\\
y(0)&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
The existence and uniqueness of the local solution $y^*$ is guaranteed by the regularity of the function
\begin{equation*}
f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y^2}{1-y}e^{-xy}
\end{equation*}
on an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$, to which the initial conditions belongs. Moreover, $y=0$ is a constant solution of the differential equation and the function $f$ is not defined on $y=1$, thus the solution $y^*(x)\in (0,1)$ for all $x\in I=(x_-,x_+)$, where $I$ is the maximal interval where the solution is defined. Now, I have to study the extensibility of the solution:
if $x_->-\infty$, then in a right neighborhood of $x_-$ we would have
\begin{equation*}
|f(x,y*(x))|\leq\frac{x_-^2}{1-y^*(x)}e^{-x_-y^*(x)}
\end{equation*}
Since the solution $y^*$ is strictly increasing in $I$ ($y^*(x)\in (0,1)$, so $y^{*'}(x)>0$ for all $x\in I$), $y^*(x)<\frac{1}{2}$, so:
\begin{equation*}
|f(x,y^*(x)|\leq 2x_-^2e^{-x_-}<+\infty
\end{equation*}
For the local extension theorem, we can extend the solution in a left neighborhood of $x_-$ and this contradicts the maximality of $I$. Thus, $x_-=-\infty$.
My problem is the situation on the right side of $x=0$: $x_+$ is finite or infinite?
Looking at the graph on Wolfram Alpha, it seems that $x_+<+\infty$, but I do not know how to prove this, since the case $x_+=+\infty$ is actually not absurd. My idea was to find a subsolution $z$ such that $z(0)=y^*(0)$ and $z$ has a vertical asymptote, but I cannot find a function $g(x,y)\leq f(x,y)$. What I can say is that, if $x_+=+\infty$, then the limit of $y^*$ at $+\infty$ can be both 1 and $l<1$ (in both cases, the limite of the derivative is 0, so we do not reach a contradiction), while if $x_+<+\infty$, the limit at $x_+$ must be necessarily 1, because otherwise the derivative would be bounded in a left neighborhood of $x_+$, thus contradicting the maximality of the interval.
Do you have any ideas how to prove this?
Thanks for any help!

You may rule out the possibility $x_+=+\infty$. Indeed, rearranging the ODE we have
$$
\frac{(1-y)y'}{y^2}=x^2e^{-xy}\geq x^2e^{-x}, \tag{1}
$$
as $\frac{1}{2}\leq y <1$ for $x\geq 0$. If we assume that $x_+=+\infty$, then Eq. $(1)$ implies
$$
\int_{1/2}^l\frac{1-y}{y^2}\,dy\geq\int_0^{\infty}x^2e^{-x}\,dx=2, \tag{2}
$$
where $l=\lim_{x\to\infty}y(x)\leq 1$. On the other hand,
$$
\int_{1/2}^l\frac{1-y}{y^2}\,dy\leq
\int_{1/2}^1\frac{1-y}{y^2}\,dy=1-\ln(2)<1, \tag{3}
$$
which contradicts the inequality $(2)$. We conclude, therefore, that $x_+$ is finite.

Good idea! Thanks a lot!
